# Use iOS inApp Purchases product identifiers of two different developer accounts for single app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Can we use iOS inApp Purchases product identifiers that created from two different developer accounts for single app?

Comment: No. The in app products must come from the same developer account as the app